# Excel Pivot Chart - Grouping by Days - X Axis Labels

Tags: excel, grouping, x-axis, pivot-chart

I am setting up a pivotchart that summarises people starting with a service from a particular area. The data being used is:

- unique person ID
- area
- date started

I want to group the days into 7 day periods. However, on the X-Axis each entry shows as Date From and Date To for each 7 day period eg 15/02/2024 - 21/02/2024.

Is there a way for the X-axis labels to just show the **Date From date** for each 7 day period. This would improve the readability of the graph immensely.

| Weeks | Number of Referrals |
| --- | --- |
| 24/03/2022 - 30/03/2022 | 1 |
| 11/01/2024 - 17/01/2024 | 27 |
| 18/01/2024 - 24/01/2024 | 37 |
| 25/01/2024 - 31/01/2024 | 35 |
| 01/02/2024 - 07/02/2024 | 22 |
| 08/02/2024 - 14/02/2024 | 28 |
| 15/02/2024 - 21/02/2024 | 33 |
| 22/02/2024 - 26/02/2024 | 22 |
| Grand Total | 1946 |

Here's a screenshot of the pivottable:

[image: Pivottable with weeks]
Thank you

Comment: Can you add some sample data using this [Markdown](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/) and a screenshot of your pivot chart?

Comment: There is this "Interval between labels" in Axis Options->Labels you can use.

Comment: Why can't you just add a column called "Week Start Date". that is, for 24/03/2022 - 30/03/2022, Week Start Date = 24/03/2022, for 11/01/2024 - 17/01/2024, week start date = 11/01/2024. and then use this "Week Start Date" as "Rows" in your pivot table?